# AWS CDK Python: Error when trying to create A Record using zone from lookup

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

Using Python3.8, CDK 2.19.0

I want to create an A Record against a hosted zone that's already in my AWS account.

I am doing the following:

```py
hosted_zone = route53.HostedZone.from_hosted_zone_attributes(self, "zone",
    zone_name="my.awesome.zone.",
    hosted_zone_id="ABC12345DEFGHI"
)

route53.ARecord(self, "app_record_set",
    target=self.lb.load_balancer_dns_name, # this is declared above, and works fine.
    zone=hosted_zone,
    record_name="test-cdk.my.awesome.zone"
)
```

Inside my `app.py` I have:

```py
env_EU = cdk.Environment(account="12345678901112", region="eu-west-1")

app = cdk.App()
create_a_record = DomianName(app, "DomianName", env=env_EU)
```

When I run `cdk synth` I get the following error:

```
➜ cdk synth
    jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
    Error: Expected object reference, got "${Token[TOKEN.303]}"
    File ".../.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 326, in send
    ...(full traceback)



Subprocess exited with error 1
```

I've tried `from_lookup` (rather than `from_hosted_zone_attributes`, Python3.9/Node 17/12/16 (just in case) but nothing is helping. I get the same error every time.

If I comment out the A Record creation, then the synth completes as expected.

`cdk.context.json` also has the correct hosted zone cached BUT only happens if I comment out the A record creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ARecord` target expects a type of [RecordTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.RecordTarget.html).  You are passing a `string` (token).  Use a [LoadBalancerTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_route53_targets/LoadBalancerTarget.html#loadbalancertarget):

```py
import aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 as elbv2

# zone: route53.HostedZone
# lb: elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer

route53.ARecord(self, "AliasRecord",
    zone=zone,
    target=route53.RecordTarget.from_alias(targets.LoadBalancerTarget(lb))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I really should RTFM. The error message told me nothing, is there a way I could have gleamed this from the traceback do you know? Or something in my setup?

Comment: @Masonator Glad to help.  The traceback's `Error` is a clue (object not string!).  CDK's Python [type annotations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-python.html#python-type-pitfalls) (e.g. with mypy) are a more systematic way to avoid type errors.

Comment: `mypy .` returns `service/service.py:60: error: Argument "target" to "ARecord" has incompatible type "str"; expected "RecordTarget"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)` exactly what I am looking for, thank you again!